# How dynamically set scss variables $body-bg and $body-color for bootstrap-vue?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I need dark/white theme switcher in my bootstrap-vue project. I have a couple scss files:

dark.scss

```
$body-bg: #333;
$body-color: #eee;

@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

white.scss

```
$body-bg: #fff;
$body-color: #000;

@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

Also I have variable crTheme in data of app. Also app.vue has watcher:

```
watch: {
    crTheme(val) {
      if (val == 'dark') {
        import('@/dark.scss')
      } else {
        import('@/white.scss')
      }
    }
  }
```

It's working ok, but only 2 times: switch to dark, then to white, and after this switching not working. As I understood I need unload bootstrap.scss and bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss and load them again on each theme switching... But I dont know how resolve this issue